# PhpStorm: Argument type is not assignable to parameter type

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, namespaces, phpstorm, jsdoc

I have come across what appears to be a bug in how PhpStorm interprets `@typedef` in JSDoc3 when used with `@namespace`. I receive the following warning..

> Argument type **item** is not assignable to parameter type **item**

..when `b(item);` is called below:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  /**
   * @namespace myNamespace
   */

  /**
   * @typedef {Object} item
   * @property {string} key
   * @property {string} value
   */

  /**
   * @function a
   * @param {item} item
   * @returns {item}
   */
  function a(item) {
    item.key = 'key';
    item.value = 'value';
    return item;
  }

  /**
   * @function b
   * @memberOf myNamespace
   * @param {item} item
   * @returns {item}
   */
  function b(item) {
    item.key = 'key';
    item.value = 'value';
    return item;
  }

  /** @type item */
  var item = {
    key: 'hello',
    value: 'world'
  };

  a(item);
  b(item);

})();
```

I only receive this warning on function b because of the `@memberOf` definition and when I remove it the warning disappears. Any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: Just to be clear, functions a and b are identical aside from b which has `@memberOf myNamespace`